Ubuntu 24 after install apparmor w can't see users not root
I installed Ubuntu 24.04 and a apparmor
root@jh:~# dpkg -l *apparmor*
ii  apparmor                4.0.1really4.0.0-beta3-0ubuntu0.1 amd64        user-space parser utility for AppArmor
un  apparmor-easyprof       <none>                            <none>       (no description available)
ii  apparmor-profiles       4.0.1really4.0.0-beta3-0ubuntu0.1 all          experimental profiles for AppArmor security policies
ii  apparmor-profiles-extra 1.35                              all          Extra profiles for AppArmor Security policies
ii  apparmor-utils          4.0.1really4.0.0-beta3-0ubuntu0.1 all          utilities for controlling AppArmor
ii  apparmor-config     1.16                              all          This Package deploys an configured
un  libapparmor-perl        <none>                            <none>       (no description available)
ii  libapparmor1:amd64      4.0.1really4.0.0-beta3-0ubuntu0.1 amd64        changehat AppArmor library
ii  libpam-apparmor         4.0.1really4.0.0-beta3-0ubuntu0.1 amd64        changehat AppArmor library as a PAM module
ii  python3-apparmor        4.0.1really4.0.0-beta3-0ubuntu0.1 all          AppArmor Python3 utility library
ii  python3-libapparmor     4.0.1really4.0.0-beta3-0ubuntu0.1 amd64        AppArmor library Python3 bindings

I installed custom package (apparmor-config) to configure it:
cat /etc/apparmor.d/pam/mappings
^DEFAULT {
   #include <abstractions/authentication>
   #include <abstractions/nameservice>
   #include <abstractions/wutmp>
   capability setgid,
   capability setuid,
   capability chown,
   capability audit_write,
   capability dac_read_search,
   /etc/environment r,
   @{HOMEDIRS}/ rwlix,
   @{HOMEDIRS}/** rwlix,
   @{HOMEDIRS}/.** rwlix,
   @{HOMEDIRS}/. rwlix,
   /logs/** rwl,
   /logs rwl,
   /tmp/** rwlix,
   /tmp/ rwlix,
   /dev/pts/[0-9]* rw,
   /dev/ptmx rw,
   / r,
   /** r,
   /var/run/sshsessions/** rw,
   /var/run/sshsessions rw,
   /usr/bin/{b,d,rb}ash Px -> default_user,
   /usr/bin/sh Px -> default_user,
   network unix dgram,
   /sbin/mkhomedir_helper rwix,
   unix (setopt,getattr,getopt,create,connect, receive, send) type=stream,
   unix (setopt,getattr,getopt,create,connect, receive, send) type=dgram,
   /proc/** r,
   /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server rix,
   /run/systemd/journal/dev-log w,
   /run/screen/ rwlix,
   /run/screen/** rwlix,
   /data/** rwlix,
   /usr/local/sbin/** rwlix,
^root {
   #include <abstractions/authentication>
   #include <abstractions/nameservice>
   capability chown,
   capability fowner,
   capability dac_override,
   capability dac_read_search,
   capability net_bind_service,
   capability net_admin,
   capability setgid,
   capability setuid,
   capability sys_admin,
   capability sys_ptrace,
   capability sys_tty_config,
   capability sys_nice,
   network unix dgram,
   capability audit_write,
   capability mac_admin,
   network unix stream,
   unix (create,connect, receive, send) type=stream,
   unix (create,connect, receive, send) type=dgram,
   / mrwlkix,
   /** mrwlkix,
   /proc/** r,
   /run/systemd/journal/dev-log w,
   /etc/environment r,
   /usr/bin/{b,d,rb}ash Ux,
   /usr/bin/sh Ux,
 }

but when I try to run the w command to see user logged, it wortks only if I'm root and show only root users.
root@jh:~# w
 16:59:49 up 31 min,  2 users,  load average: 0.14, 0.19, 0.18
USER     TTY      FROM             LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
root     pts/2    -                16:36   10:21   0.32s  0.01s tail -f /var/log/audit/audit.log
root     pts/4    -                16:51    0.00s  0.06s  0.02s sudo su -

ubuntu@jh.mydomain.local:~$ w
 17:00:11 up 31 min,  2 users,  load average: 0.17, 0.19, 0.18
USER     TTY      FROM             LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
root     pts/2    -                16:36   10:43   0.32s  0.01s tail -f /var/log/audit/audit.log
root     pts/4    -                16:51   22.00s  0.06s  0.02s sudo su -

The custom package works fine with Ubuntu 20.04
Any advice how can fix it?
Thanks in advance for your help.
